# Astar loops forever when the goal is unreachable?

Tags: python, path-finding, a-star

I'm following the #1 recommended tutorial for A* pathfinding [on this website](https://www.redblobgames.com/pathfinding/a-star/introduction.html). I'm at the part where he provides the code for A*:

```
frontier = PriorityQueue()
frontier.put(start, 0)
came_from = dict()
cost_so_far = dict()
came_from[start] = None
cost_so_far[start] = 0

while not frontier.empty():
   current = frontier.get()

   if current == goal:
      break
   
   for next in graph.neighbors(current):
      new_cost = cost_so_far[current] + graph.cost(current, next)
      if next not in cost_so_far or new_cost < cost_so_far[next]:
         cost_so_far[next] = new_cost
         priority = new_cost + heuristic(goal, next)
         frontier.put(next, priority)
         came_from[next] = current
```

I've implemented this exactly, and it works. I've set up some complicated grids and it works on all of them, but only if the path is possible. If the goal is unreachable from the start, because it is impossible, then it loops forever.

How does one modify this code to account for that? I'm sure it's a simple solution but I am still very new to A* and was not sure on the ideal way to handle this edge-case.

Comment: The basic answer to this is that you research the [full A* algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm), compare it with what you have, and modify your code accordingly.  Asking us to modify third-party code for your needs is out of scope for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Well the third-party code basically _is_ my code at this point because I copied it verbatim.

Comment: Where's the closed set?

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: I am not familiar with A* pathfinding algorithm but have you tried storing the initial point and comparing all upcoming points with the stored one. If they matches, It means they are repeating and you may end the loop based on that.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I figured it out. From the linked tutorial I had to modify the `get_path` code to be the following:

```
current = goal 
path = []
while current != start: 
   if current is None: # added this
     return []         # and this
   path.append(current)
   current = came_from[current]
path.append(start) # optional
path.reverse() # optional
```